# LateInitializationError: Field '_recognitions@25356196' has not been initialized

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I keep getting the error above whenever I run my Flutter code. The code below is my dart file which I get the problem from. I tried debugging but couldn't get an answer and the project is delaying me because I still have some unfinished ones. Pls I hope I can get an answer for this error.

> The error is Another exception was thrown: LateInitializationError: Field '_recognitions@25356196' has not
> been initialized. Thank you.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'bounding_box.dart';
import 'camera.dart';
import 'dart:math' as math;
import 'package:tflite/tflite.dart';

// ignore: must_be_immutable
class LiveFeed extends StatefulWidget {
   List<CameraDescription> cameras;
  // ignore: use_key_in_widget_constructors
   LiveFeed(this.cameras);
  @override
  // ignore: library_private_types_in_public_api
  _LiveFeedState createState() => _LiveFeedState();
}

class _LiveFeedState extends State<LiveFeed> {
  late List<dynamic> _recognitions;
  int _imageHeight = 0;
  int _imageWidth = 0;
  initCameras() async {

  }
  loadTfModel() async {
    await Tflite.loadModel(
      model: "assets/models/ssd_mobilenet.tflite",
      labels: "assets/models/labels.txt",
    );
  }
  /* 
  The set recognitions function assigns the values of recognitions, imageHeight and width to the variables defined here as callback
  */
  setRecognitions(recognitions, imageHeight, imageWidth) {
    setState(() {
      _recognitions = recognitions;
      _imageHeight = imageHeight;
      _imageWidth = imageWidth;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() { 
    super.initState();
    loadTfModel();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size screen = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Orange AI"),
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          CameraFeed(widget.cameras, setRecognitions),
          BoundingBox(
            // ignore: unnecessary_null_comparison
            _recognitions,
            math.max(_imageHeight, _imageWidth),
            math.min(_imageHeight, _imageWidth),
            screen.height,
            screen.width,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

My Terminal

````
Another exception was thrown: LateInitializationError: Field '_recognitions@25356196' has not
been initialized.```
````

Answer (score 0):

You have not initialized `late List<dynamic> _recognitions;` and the simplest solution is remove `late` and initialize it with empty list.

```
List<dynamic> _recognitions = [];
```

If you wan't to remove `late`, make sure it has been initialized before You use it on `build`. You can initialize it on `initState`.